# Rename My account tabbed menu items in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tabs, account

I am currently using Wordpress Version 4.9.8 and enabled Woocommerce plugin. I need to rename the tab name "Dashboard" to "My Rewards" in My account pages.

I found the code below, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
function wpb_woo_endpoint_title( $title, $id ) {
   if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'dashboard' ) && in_the_loop() ) { // add your endpoint urls
     $title = "My Rewards"; // change your entry-title
     return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpb_woo_endpoint_title', 10, 2 );
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks sir @LoicTheAztec, That is so fast response. Its working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following instead *(Works in Woocommerce since version 2.6)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'custom_my_account_menu_items', 22, 1 );
function custom_my_account_menu_items( $items ) {
    $items['dashboard'] = __("My Rewards", "woocommerce");
    return $items;
}
```

This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]